# Generate new images based on a dataset of images

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, image-classification

Is it possible take a training set of one million 120 x 120 pixel tiles, feed these tiles into a machine learning algorithm. And then make it *synthesize* images that look like the original training set with a certain, adjustable level of entropy?

What ML techniques should I consider?

Comment: This might help: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/tijmen_thesis.pdf . . . although I don't know enough to turn that into a full answer, perhaps someone else will.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are plenty ways to do this, what you basically want is to interpolate between the two.

This is current state-of-the-art for solving problems like yours: https://github.com/carpedm20/BEGAN-tensorflow

Also keep an eye out for my question here: [2D Image-based Avatar Animation With Expressions / Image-To-Image Translation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20533/2d-image-based-avatar-animation-with-expressions-image-to-image-translation)

If I end up using the ML approach, you could very well also use it with tiles instead of faces and be able to adjust the likeness. I will link to my project in my question.